# Suma Polinomios en C

Tags: c

Estoy realizando una suma de polinomios haciendo uso de struct con arreglos dinámicos. Pero al momento de realizar la suma de polinomios me sale este error. Y se duplican también los datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código:

Mis declaración de las estructuras a usar.

```
typedef struct{ 

int coeficiente, 
      exponente;
      
}Termino;

typedef struct{

Termino termino;

}Polinomio;
```

A continuación muestro donde se pueden leer los datos. Hasta el momento lee y muestra los datos correctamente. Sin embargo cuando realizo la suma de polinomios, se rompe mi programa.

```
void LeerPolinomio(Polinomio *polinomio, int cantidadPolinomio){

int i;

for(i = 0; i < cantidadPolinomio; i++){
    
    printf("\n\n:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::\n");
    printf("Polinomio: %d\n", i + 1);
    printf(":::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::\n");
    
    printf("Digite coeficiente del cuadrado: "); 
    scanf("%d", &polinomio[i].termino.coeficiente);     

    printf("Digite coeficiente de grado 1: "); 
    scanf("%d", &polinomio[i].termino.exponente);
    
}

}
```

Como comente anteriormente los módulos de leer y mostrar los polinomios funcionan sin ningún problema. Adjunto código:

void MostrarPolinomio(Polinomio *polinomio, int cantidadPolinomio){

```
 int i;

for(i = 0; i < cantidadPolinomio; i++){// muestra los datos guardados
    
    if(polinomio[i].termino.coeficiente >= 0){
        
        printf(" + ");
        
    }
    
    printf(" %d", polinomio[i].termino.coeficiente);
        
    printf("x%d", polinomio[i].termino.exponente);

}
```

}

Hasta el momento también me muestra correctamente los datos de salida de dicho polinomio. Sin ningún error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto código de la suma de polinomios. Es donde se rompe y deja de funcionar el programa.

```
void SumaPolinomios(Polinomio *polinomio1, Polinomio *polinomio2, Polinomio *suma, int cantidadPolinomio){

int i, k, j;

i = j = k = 0;

while(i < cantidadPolinomio){
            
    if(polinomio1[i].termino.exponente > polinomio2[i].termino.exponente){
        
        suma[k++].termino = polinomio1[i++].termino;
        
    }else{
        
        if(polinomio1[i].termino.exponente < polinomio2[i].termino.exponente){

            suma[k++].termino = polinomio2[i++].termino;
                        
        }else{
        
            suma[k].termino.exponente = polinomio1[i].termino.exponente;
            
            suma[k++].termino.coeficiente = polinomio1[i++].termino.coeficiente + polinomio2[i++].termino.coeficiente;
                
        }
    
    }
    
}
    
for(i = 1; i < cantidadPolinomio; i++){
    
    suma[k++].termino = polinomio1[i].termino;
    
}

for(j = 0; j < cantidadPolinomio; j++){

    suma[k++].termino = polinomio2[j].termino;

}

MostrarPolinomio(suma, k);
```

}

Y en este módulo es donde tengo el problema. Donde se rompe el programa.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! se rompe y deja de funcionar... y nosotros tenemos que adivinar porque? si se rompe, tira algun error no? que error? si deja de funcionar, tira un error no? que error?? como haces la llamada a esa funcion que suma? esta todo bien definido? por favor, usa el boton [edit] y completa tu pregunta....

Comment: ¿En los bucles `for` no asignas un valor inicial...?

Comment: @Francisco Javier no, porque lo hace al comienzo de la función

Comment: Ya, pero si no le dices al bucle `for` donde tiene que empezar, ¿cómo va a saber con qué comparar `j < cantidadPolinomio;`, por ejemplo ...?

Comment: @FranciscoJavier te lo han dicho... Tiene la asignación al comienzo del modo: `i = j = k = 0;` ¿Recomendable hacerlo así? Desde mi punto de vista no, pero si el OP se aclara de esa manera..

Comment: También tiene `i++` y `j++` en el bloque `while`... ¿Qué valen `i` o `j` en el bucle `for`?